# MySQL table recovery from crashed server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, recovery, frm

I managed to wipe a server by mistake but PhotoRec was kind enough to recover the .frm and .myi files from the hard drive. I now have a desktop set up with the same version of MySQL to recover the data but my question is: what do I do? I have about 160 of these files. I haven't yet reinstalled the server in case I need anything else.

Also, as I'm using PhotoRec, it doesn't provide the original filenames. If this is important, how can I get the raw data out of the files and manually rebuild the database?

Edit: I managed to get ahold of the PhotoRec source and add the capability to recover the .myd files (which a bit of digging reveals to be the actual data files), but I can't get the thing to compile, and it ain't because of my mods! Can anyone help with a 'No rule to make target' error in PhotoRec? file_http.o's the culprit.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Related reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk.html

Comment: Consider asking here [http://dba.stackexchange.com/](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

MYI files are useless, these are files with secondary indexes, not your data.

PhotoRec is a nice tool, I used it a lot for multimedia recovery etc. Although it claims MYD support it never worked for me. I doubt it possibly can extract MYD files.

Answer (score 0):

I dont belive you can, photorec does not support MYD, im doing an attempt with ext3grep but it always segfaults.

just posting this so someone doesnt spend time better spent on using photorec for this purpose.